# Maths Quiz Task Python

Tags: python, math

I have been set a task to program a math's quiz. The basic code was given to me and I was set a series of challenges to make it more complex. My method to check if the final score is in a certain range doesn't work as it should, the instructions were to check if the user scored 66% or more, if they did then the program should print "Well done!". If the user scored between 33% and 66% the program should print "You need more practice" and if they scored less than 33% then it would print "Please ask your math teacher for help". However this does not happen and there are some weird results. Any help is appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
from random import randint 

while True:

    correct = 0

    userrange = int(input("How many questions would you like?\n"))

    difficulty = input("Choose your difficulty: beginner, intermediate or advanced?\n")

    if difficulty == "beginner":
            no = 10
    if difficulty == "intermediate":
            no = 25
    if difficulty == "advanced":
            no = 100


    qtype = input("Would you like to do addition, subtraction or multiplication?\n")    

    if qtype == "addition":
        for i in range(userrange):
            n1 = randint(1, no)
            n2 = randint(1, no)
            prod = n1 + n2
            lo = "plus"
    if qtype == "subtraction":
        for i in range(userrange):
            n1 = randint(1, no)
            n2 = randint(1, no)
            prod = n1 - n2
            lo = "minus"
    if qtype == "multiplication":
        for i in range(userrange):
            n1 = randint(1, no)
            n2 = randint(1, no)
            prod = n1 * n2
            lo = "times"


    ans = int(input("What's %d %s %d?"  % (n1 ,lo ,n2)))
    if ans == prod:
        print ("That's right -- well done.\n")
        correct = correct + 1
    else:
        print ("No, I'm afraid the answer is %d.\n" % prod)



    print ("\nI asked you %d questions.  You got %d of them right." %(userrange, correct))
    if correct >= (userrange%3)*2:
        print ("Well done!")
    elif (userrange%3) < correct < (userrange%3)*2:
        print ("You need more practice")
    else:
        print ("Please ask your maths teacher for help!")


    try_again = int(input("\nPress 1 to try again, press 0 to exit.\n "))
    if try_again == 0:
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close... you just need to move the positioning of your loop a little bit so that it catches the actual asking of the question.

As it stands now, you're only looping over the part where you generate the questions.

I'll post the entire code here since there is a bit of indentation changes to support the new loop:

```
from random import randint 

while True:
    correct = 0

    userrange = int(input("How many questions would you like?\n"))

    difficulty = input("Choose your difficulty: beginner, intermediate or advanced?\n")

    if difficulty == "beginner":
            no = 10
    if difficulty == "intermediate":
            no = 25
    if difficulty == "advanced":
            no = 100

    qtype = input("Would you like to do addition, subtraction or multiplication?\n")    

    for i in range(userrange):  # Move the loop to start here, instead of under each if / elif
        n1 = randint(1, no)  # We can go ahead and generate our random numbers here also
        n2 = randint(1, no)
        if qtype == "addition":
            prod = n1 + n2
            lo = "plus"
        elif qtype == "subtraction":
            prod = n1 - n2
            lo = "minus"
        elif qtype == "multiplication":
            prod = n1 * n2
            lo = "times"


        ans = int(input("What's %d %s %d?"  % (n1 ,lo ,n2)))  # We also need to move the question into the loop, so that it is asked each time
        if ans == prod:
            print ("That's right -- well done.\n")
            correct = correct + 1
        else:
            print ("No, I'm afraid the answer is %d.\n" % prod)



    print ("\nI asked you %d questions.  You got %d of them right." %(userrange, correct))
    if correct >= (userrange%3)*2:
        print ("Well done!")
    elif (userrange%3) < correct < (userrange%3)*2:
        print ("You need more practice")
    else:
        print ("Please ask your maths teacher for help!")


    try_again = int(input("\nPress 1 to try again, press 0 to exit.\n "))
    if try_again == 0:
        break
```